# Recommended pattern/strategy to compare two sets of data (new vs existing)... remaining with new data that's not in existing

Tags: c#, etl

I have an ETL process/job that fetches database data from a source to a destination in a scheduled way.

1. `[Source data]` is updated regularly with new data from some external
   source. `[Destination data]` is a subset of `[Source data]` that is used
   downstream by business.
2. The constraint requirement in `[Destination data]` is that it should
   not have duplicates (may occur, for example, in the event of job
   failure, then a new extraction is run after some data is possible imported)
3. The job imports 1000 records at a time
4. The Scheduler/Job has other responsibilities and other data it works on

One of my "feasible" options involve:

- fetching **ALL the projected composite/key columns from the destination**,
- doing a comparison with the new 1000 loaded records (still alot of
  records).
- Then saving the new `[Source data]` that is not in the
  `[Destination Data]`.
- I would imagine that the data structure containing existing `[Destination data]` would be a [Hashset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the following structure, for example, `HashSet<int,string,string>`. Where the 3 data items uniquely identify a record.
- I would then get the 1000 records, loop through them, comparing with the HashSet.

I fear working with too much data in-memory.

**Any advice on a better approach, or would this be the most efficient way to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share, I found similar question with a comprehensive answer. It's in Java but easily translates to C#.

Still open to any alternatives. Otherwise will mark this one as answer and indicate as being duplicate.

---

...we could sort all elements by their ID (a one-time `O(n log n)` cost) in ascending order, and iterate over them using an `O(n)` algorithm that skips elements as long as they are larger than the current element from the other sequence. This is better, but still not optimal.

The optimal solution is to create a hash set of IDs of the `bs` set. This does not require sorting of both sets, and allows linear-time membership test. There is a one-time `O(n)` cost to assemble the set of IDs.

```java
HashSet<Integer> bIds = new HashSet<>(bs.size());
for (B b : bs)
    bIDs.add(b.getId());

for (A a : as)
    if (bIds.contains(a.getId()))
        cs.add(a);
```

The total complexity of this solution is `O(|as| + |bs|)`.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/258325/132218